# Check whether the date range in a certain Month

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to make a formula for a date range is in the certain month?

Eg 1 : 1/1/2021 - 23/3/2021 output will say January 2021 - 31 days, February 2021 - 28 days and March 2021 - 23 days

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TEXT(SEQUENCE((B1+1)-A1, 1, A1), "mmmm yyyy"), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]

if you need it sorted use:

```
=INDEX(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY(TEXT(SEQUENCE((B1+1)-A1, 1, A1), {"mmmm yyyy", "yyyymm"}), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1),Col2 group by Col1,Col2 order by Col2 label count(Col1)''"), 9^9, 2))
```

[image]

Comment: Omg good output! But i have thousands rows . Is there any possibility to make it transpose to the right ?

Comment: @Biha either wrap it into `TRANSPOSE()` or if you need to flatten it into single row, wrap it into `TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN())`